# Change host from 127.0.0.1 to my ip JBoss EAP

Tags: server, jboss, host, jboss-eap-6

I want to change the url to my web-app, i tries to change the interfaces in standalone.xml, but the app still running at 127.0.0.1:port.

my interfaces from standalone.xml:

```
 <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.24.216}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.24.216}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.24.216}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

What file I need to modify? Is JBoss EAP 6.4

Comment: Did you shut down the server before you made those changes? You can also start with `standalone.sh -b=192.168.24.216`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins i did this and worked, i builta batch with that startup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your application will still run on the local machine but you should be able to access it via your IP if you correctly port forward your router. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw) explains how portforwarding works.